# How to filter GraphQL nested array on field returning in same query's response? Or how to create GraphQL relationship on more than one field?

Tags: android, postgresql, graphql, apollo, hasura

So I'm using GraphQL with Hasura and Apollo in my Android application. The application is related to sports, it stores multiple score sets of each player in multiple segments of a match. My Postgres database has following tables (with concerned fields):

```
Match (id, other_fields...)
Segment (id, match_id, other_fields...)
Segment_Player (id, segment_id, player_id)
Player (id, other_fields...)
Score (id, segment_id, player_id, other_fields...)
```

`Segment_Player` is a many to many bridge table between `Segment` and `Player` tables. There are array relationships from `Match` to `Segment` and from `Player` to `Score`.

I want to query scores of each player in a match separated by segments. Response I want should be like following structure:

```
Match
--Segment
----Player
------Score
```

The problem I'm facing is that I cannot find a way to filter scores on both `PlayerId` and `SegmentId`. `Player` - `Score` relation can give me all scores of that player. Or I can create a relation between `Segment` and `Score` which will give me scores of every player in that segment. But either of these will still leave me with filtering to do on client side.

What I want is to be able to provide data returning in response as argument in where clause like below:

```
query PointsQuery($matchId: String!) {
  SegmentQL: segment(where: {matchId: {_eq: $matchId}}) {
    SegmentId: id
    segment_player {
      player {
        ...PlayerQL
        scores(where: {segmentId: {_eq: SegmentId}}) {
          ...ScoreQL
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How to achieve this without filtering data on client side.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is super late, but the query will work as-is, without the second where clause

```
query PointsQuery($matchId: String!) {
  SegmentQL: segment(where: {matchId: {_eq: $matchId}}) {
    SegmentId: id
    segment_player {
      player {
        ...PlayerQL
        scores {
          ...ScoreQL
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Because you will only get the players related to that segment and then you will only get the scores related to that player for that segment.

If scores are actually related to a segment and you want all scores for that segment, instead of all scores related to that player for that segment, you should add another relationship

```
query PointsQuery($matchId: String!) {
  SegmentQL: segment(where: {matchId: {_eq: $matchId}}) {
    SegmentId: id
    score {
      ...ScoreQL
    }
    segment_player {
      player {
        ...PlayerQL
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and sorry for super super late reply. I did find a work around for this problem.
Alas none of your suggestions would have actually worked for me.

Comment: I should have mentioned that a player can be in more than one match/segment, so if I follow your first solution than I would get all scores of that player from each and every match/segment.

Comment: As for your second solution, I'd already mentioned in my question that I can get all scores in a segment using Segment - Score relationship, but that would mean that I've to map scores to each player on client side. That is no good either.

Comment: Anyways, thank you for answering, as you are the only one who did come up with a possible solution. I think I managed to solve it by creating a relationship between Segment_Player and Score tables.